# akka-http with multiple route configurations

Tags: scala, akka-http

### Quick Background

I am running through some examples learning the Akka HTTP stack for creating a new REST project (completely non-UI).  I have been using and augmenting the [Akka HTTP Microservice Example](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-http-microservice) to work through a bunch of use cases and configurations and have been pleasantly surprised by how well Scala & Akka HTTP work.

### Current Setup

Currently I have a configuration like this:

```
object AkkaHttpMicroservice extends App with Service {
  override implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  override implicit val executor = system.dispatcher
  override implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  override val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  override val logger = Logging(system, getClass)

  Http().bindAndHandle(routes, config.getString("http.interface"), config.getInt("http.port"))
}
```

The `routes` parameter is just a simple value that has the typical data within it using `path`, `pathPrefix`, etc.

### The Problem

Is there any way to set up routing in multiple Scala files or an example somewhere out there?

I would really like to be able to define a set of classes that separate the concerns and deal with Actor setup and processing to deal with different areas of the application and just leave the marshaling to the root `App` extension.

This might be me thinking too much in terms of how I did things in Java using annotations like `@javax.ws.rs.Path("/whatever")` on my classes.  If that is the case, please feel free to point out the change in mindset.

I tried searching for a few different set of keywords but believe I am asking the wrong question (eg, [1](https://www.google.com/search?q=akka-http+route+definitions+in+multiple+locations&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), [2](https://www.google.com/search?q=akka-http+route+definitions+in+multiple+locations&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=akka-http+using+implicits+to+define+route+handling)).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Problem 1 - combine routes in multiple files**

You can combine routes from multiple files quite easy.

FooRouter.scala

```
object FooRouter {
   val route = path("foo") {
       complete {
          Ok -> "foo"
       } 
   }       
}
```

BarRouter.scala

```
object BarRouter {
   val route = path("bar") {
       complete {
          Ok -> "bar"
       } 
   }       
}
```

MainRouter.scala

```
import FooRouter
import BarRouter
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import ...

object MainRouter {
   val routes = FooRouter.route ~ BarRouter.route
}

object AkkaHttpMicroservice extends App with Service {
  ...    
  Http().bindAndHandle(MainRouter.routes, config.getString("http.interface"), config.getInt("http.port"))
}
```

Here you have have some docs :

- http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/overview.html
- http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/routes.html

**Problem 2 - seprate routing, marshalling, etc**

Yes, you can separate routing, marshalling and application logic. Here you have  activator example: https://github.com/theiterators/reactive-microservices

**Problem 3 - handle routes using annotations**

I don't know any lib that allow you to use annotion to define routing in akka-http. Try to learn more about DSL routing. This represents a different approach to http routing but it is convenient tool too.

Comment: Thanks.  Looking up the DSL routing set me down a good path and shifted my approach a bit.  It seems to be the more appropriate mindset for approaching my particular problem at hand.  The thing with Problem 1 is that I was trying to avoid having to edit multiple files (i.e., the separate file and then adding the route concatenation in the app).

Comment: This was driving me nuts. I used http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/routes.html#the-routing-tree and it worked fine. Previously used `FooRouter.route ~ BarRouter.route` but it was throwing some unmarshalling exception. Thanks for saving my hair.

Comment: Worth saying that you need to write `import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._` for this to work. Doc: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/routes.html#composing-routes

Comment: Using this approach causes an error for me: `Http().bindAndHandle(MainRouter.routes` for me is throwing an error, it's saying `Type mismatch, expected: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any], actual: server.Route`